# Dynamically change a Control's ContextMenuStrip property at runtime?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, contextmenustrip

I have a DataGridView that I want to use one ContextMenuStrip if a cell is right-clicked and a different ContextMenuStrip if a Cell Header is clicked. I **DO NOT** want to just add or remove or make visible or invisible members of the "same" CMS. I thought that it would be as easy as changing the DataGridView's property on a right-click, but I must be mistaken.

```
Private Sub DgvItems_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DgvItems.CellClick
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DgvItems
    If MouseButtons.Right Then
        Select Case md.HitTestInfo.Type
            Case DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader
                dgv.ContextMenuStrip = CmsDgvItemsColHdrs
                dgv.ContextMenuStrip.Show()
            Case DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell
                dgv.ContextMenuStrip = CmsDgvItemsRows
                dgv.ContextMenuStrip.Show()
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Duh. Maybe if I had the RIGHT EVENT the first time it would have worked.

Here's the proper code with NO need to "`dgv.ContextMenuStrip.Show()`" again...

```
Private Sub DgvItems_CellMouseDown(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs) Handles DgvItems.CellMouseDown
    Dim dgv As DataGridView = DgvItems
    If MouseButtons.Right Then
        Select Case md.HitTestInfo.Type
            Case DataGridViewHitTestType.ColumnHeader
                dgv.ContextMenuStrip = CmsDgvItemsColHdrs
            Case DataGridViewHitTestType.Cell
                dgv.ContextMenuStrip = CmsDgvItemsRows
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```